# OneToMany and ManyToOne Report generate through hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations, reporting, using

I have two class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AFFILIATES")
class Affiliate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name= "affiliate_id")
    private String affiliateId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="affiliate", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AffiliateInvoice> affiliateInvoice;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="affiliate", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Payments> payments;

    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    public String getAffiliateId() {
        return affiliateId;
    }

    public void setAffiliateId(String affiliateId) {
        this.affiliateId = affiliateId;
    }

    public Set<AffiliateInvoice> getAffiliateInvoice() {
        return affiliateInvoice;
    }

    public void setAffiliateInvoice(Set<AffiliateInvoice> affiliateInvoice) {
        this.affiliateInvoice = affiliateInvoice;
    }

    public Set<Payments> getPayments() {
        return payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(Set<Payments> payments) {
        this.payments = payments;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="AFFILIATE_INVOICE")
class AffiliateInvoice implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="invoice_id")
    private Integer invoiceId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="affiliate_id")
    private Affiliate affiliate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="payment_id")
    private Payments payments;

    public Integer getInvoiceId() {
        return invoiceId;
    }

    public void setInvoiceId(Integer invoiceId) {
        this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
    }

    public Affiliate getAffiliate() {
        return affiliate;
    }

    public void setAffiliate(Affiliate affiliate) {
        this.affiliate = affiliate;
    }

    public Payments getPayments() {
        return payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(Payments payments) {
        this.payments = payments;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name= "PAYMENTS")
class Payments implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="payment_id")
    private Integer paymentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="merchant_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")
    private Affiliate affiliate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="payment_id", nullable=true)
    private AffiliateInvoice affiliateInvoice;

    @Column(name="amount")
    private Double amount;

    public Integer getPaymentId() {
        return paymentId;
    }

    public void setPaymentId(Integer paymentId) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }

    public Affiliate getAffiliate() {
        return affiliate;
    }

    public void setAffiliate(Affiliate affiliate) {
        this.affiliate = affiliate;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public AffiliateInvoice getAffiliateInvoice() {
        return affiliateInvoice;
    }

    public void setAffiliateInvoice(AffiliateInvoice affiliateInvoice) {
        this.affiliateInvoice = affiliateInvoice;
    }
}
```

Now I there may be chance that affiliate may or may not have the invoices.

Now Affiliate has Payments, but some affiliate may yet not generate the invoice.

so How can I retrieve all the details that how many affiliate has generate the invoice and how many are pending?

I did some thing like as follows.

```
Session s = connection.getSession();
            String hql = "from Affiliate as a " +
                    " inner join fetch a.payments as mp " +
                    " inner join fetch a.affiliateInvoice as ai " +
                    " where ai.invoiceId = 270";
                    Query q = s.createQuery(hql);

                    AffiliateInvoice ai = (AffiliateInvoice) q.uniqueResult();

                    System.out.println(ai);
```

But it is not giving the resule

I want something like follow.

```
AffiliateId    PaymentId   isInvoiceGenerated
aaa              111             Y
bbb              222             N
ccc              333             N
ddd              444             Y
```

How can i Get such Result ?

If I do something like as follow

```
Session s = connection.getSession();
            String hql = "from com.infibeam.test.oneToMany.Affiliate as a " +
                    " inner join fetch a.payments as mp " +
                    " left join fetch a.affiliateInvoice as ai "
```

then it gives me

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Affiliate cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.type.StringType.toString(StringType.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.toLoggableString(NullableType.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.collectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:284)
```